# About Push notification with google play services issue

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, google-play-services

I encounter the problem with Push notification below:

> On 1 phone, I'm receiving push notification well.
>   I delete google play service, after install latest version of google play services then I can not receive push.
>   Now I installed old version of google play service, but I also can not receive push on this phone.
>   Do you know about this issue?

I tried with demo code of google [here](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/start)
It don't work on this phone.

Comment: Have u updated your instance id ?

Comment: Hi @AnixPasBesoin : I don't know about **instance id**.
I'm using demo code of google at here : https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/start
Could you give some explain about that ?

Answer (score 1):

Because Token is generated when google play services installed on device so when you uninstall the google play services and reinstall new version then you have to get token then only you receive push notification.

Comment: Hi @Bhavinkumar Patel : I'm using demo gcm of google at [here](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/start).
But I also could not receive push. Do you know any way to resolve this issue ?